# SQL Question Looking Up Value in Same Table

Tags: sql, join, null, self-join

Trying to use a self join in SQL to look up a value in the table and apply it.

Her's what I got:

+-----------------+-----+--------+-----------+

|  Acutal Output  |     |        |           |

+-----------------+-----+--------+-----------+

| TRKID           | Fac | NewFac | BAG_TRKID |

| 449             | 11  | 11     | 999       |

| 473             | 11  | 11     | 737       |

| 477             | 11  | 11     | 737       |

| 482             | 11  | 11     | 737       |

| 737             | 89  | 89     |           |

---

| Desired Out Put |     |        |           |

| TRKID           | Fac | NewFac | BAG_TRKID |

| 449             | 11  | 11     | 999       |

| 473             | 11  | 89     | 737       |

| 477             | 11  | 89     | 737       |

| 482             | 11  | 89     | 737       |

| 737             | 89  | 89     |           |

+-----------------+-----+--------+-----------+

Here's the code below. I can't seem to get the table that I want. The Bag TrkID's Facility Num is not becoming the TrkID New Facility Num.

```
Select 
    TABLEA.TRKID,
    TABLEA.FAC,
    NVL(TABLEA.FAC, TABLEB.FAC) as NEWFAC,
    TABLEA.BAG_TRKID        

FROM
    (
    Select
    HSD. TRKID,
    HSD.NLPT as FAC,
    SBPD.BAG_TRKID
    From
    HSD
    LEFT JOIN
    SBPD
    ON
    SBPD.BAG_TRKID = HSD. TRKID

Where
    HSD.SCANDT BETWEEN   ‘Yesterday’ and ‘Today’
) TABLEA

LEFT JOIN
(
    Select
    HSD. TRKID,
    HSD.NLPT as FAC,
    SBPD.BAG_TRKID
    From
    HSD
    LEFT JOIN
    SBPD
    ON
    SBPD.BAG_TRKID = HSD. TRKID

Where                              
    HSD.SCANDT BETWEEN   ‘Yesterday’ and ‘Today’
) TABLEB

ON
TABLEA.TRKID = TABLEB.BAG_TRKID
```

Comment: Mind sharing your SQL code with us?

Comment: Also, which RDBMS are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like

```
select a.TrkID, a."Facility Number", a.BAG_TRKID, b.TrkID as "NEW Fac"
from tbl a
left join tbl b on (a.TrkID = b.trk_id_reference)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the limited information that you've shared, I was able to achieve the expected output with the following query:

```
SELECT a.TrkID, a.facility_number, a.bag_trkid, b.facility_number as new_facility_number 
FROM test_tbl AS a 
 LEFT JOIN test_tbl AS b ON a.bag_trkid = b.trkid OR (a.bag_trkid IS NULL AND b.trkid = a.trkid);
```

You want to get the new_facility_number for a row based on its bag_trkid (which can be achieved by this: `LEFT JOIN test_tbl AS b ON a.bag_trkid = b.trkid`).
BUT the trick is to account for the cases when the Left Table (which I refer as a) does not have a bag_trkid. In this case, we will keep the new_facility_number to be the same as a.facility_number, joining the tables on the trkid solely: `OR (a.bag_trkid IS NULL AND b.trkid = a.trkid)`